# How does rotating a beam splitter (cube) affect the output angles?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics

Normally, you would want to place a beam splitter at 45 degrees with respect to the input beam. This way, it splits the light 50/50 and the output beams are aligned for sure. Like this:

[image]

Now, I want to know what happens to the angles of the output beam when the cube is *not* aligned to the optical axis, as shown below. I could find that [the reflectivity/transmittance deviate from 50%](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Beamsplitter_Performance_Lab_Fact.pdf), but I could not find what would happen to the angles of the output beam. Does anyone know this? This would greatly help me with alignment!
[image]

P.S. I want to know for a cube beam splitter, but for future reference it might also be good to include plate- and pellice beam splitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Short answer:

- The transmitted beam has the same direction as the incident beam. It is only shifted by
  $$d = a \left( \sin \alpha - \frac{\cos \alpha}{\sqrt{\frac{\left( \frac{n_\text{glass}}{n_\text{air}} \right)^2}{\sin^2 \alpha} - 1}} \right),$$
  where $\alpha$ is the tilt angle, $a$ is the edge length of the beamsplitter cube and $n_\text{glass}$ and $n_\text{air}$ are the refractive indices of the beamsplitter material and the surrounding medium, respectively.
- The reflected beam is rotated by $2\alpha$ when the beamsplitter is rotated by $\alpha$. This is the same as when a simple mirror is rotated.

[image]

##### Why the same as for a normal mirror?

For this, we can consider the symmetry axis as shown in the figure below. Because of this symmetry, we know that $\alpha' = \beta'$, which are connected to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ via [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law)
$$\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin{\alpha '}} = \frac{n_\text{glass}}{n_\text{air}} = \frac{\sin \beta}{\sin{\beta '}}.$$
The reflected beam exits the cube at an angle $\beta = \alpha$ to the surface normal, while the entering beam is at an angle $\alpha$ to the surface normal of the entrance face of the cube. In the drawn example, the entering beam is rotated clockwise from the surface normal, whereas the exiting beam is rotated counterclockwise from the corresponding surface normal. The overall deflection of the beam due to the rotation is therefore $\alpha + \beta = 2\alpha$. 
[image]

##### Other beamsplitters

- Pellicle beamsplitter: The same as with a regular mirror, because the reflection occurs at a thin surface.
- Plate beamsplitter: The same as with a regular mirror, because it should be set up such that the laser is incident on the semi-reflective side to avoid multiple reflections within the plate. However, even if the plate beamsplitter is used the other way round, you can apply the same symmetry arguments as above. Some beamsplitter plates are slightly wedged – in that case the symmetry does not hold true exactly.

Comment: Very helpful and I love the figures as well!